# Rails autocomplete 50k records

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete

The database stores 50,000 records. Records have a title and id.
I need to do a search by title with autocomplete.

Is *jQuery UI + ajax* suitable for this? Or are there faster ways to do this?

For ajax, will I need to do `MyRecord.all` in the index action?
Then forward the ajax request to this action?

Comment: jQueryUI and AJAX are half of the solution. I'd be more concerned with database performance, and ensuring you can quickly search by a given filter string on the server side, all while maintaining performance when there's N users concurrently making requests.

Comment: Also, if it wasn't clear from the above, dumping 50,000 records to the client side via AJAX to search through is not a workable solution. You will need to filter on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do the autocompletion on the server side. Loading 50k records from the DB to Rails, serializing it to JSON and parsing in JS will be *quite* slow.

Possible solutions for finding matches:

- SQL `LIKE` - highly discourage, unless you autocomplete on prefixes only, it's impossible to index it
- [Postgres `pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgtrgm.html)
- [elastic completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-suggesters-completion.html)
- [Mysql ngram](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html)

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL then [`LIKE` will use trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/479863).